# Plot 2 or more curves on same graph with same scale but different x-ranges

Tags: plotting

I have two functions $f1$ and $f2$.

I know I can plot them on the same graph doing this :

```
Plot[{f1[x],f2[x]},{x,xmin,xmax}]
```

But how can I choose one range for $f1$ and another for $f2$ such that $xmin^1 \neq xmin^2$ for example ?

Remark : I am looking for a very simple code, the linked proposed seems a little too "complicated". But the comment proposed answered my question

EDIT :

The following code just plot one curve for me :

```
    Show[Plot[Sin[\[CapitalDelta]I], {\[CapitalDelta]I, -2, 0}], 
 Plot[Cos[\[CapitalDelta]I], {\[CapitalDelta]I, -1, 0}]]
```

I only see the Sin and not the Cos here.

[image]

Comment: A simple workaround could be `Show[Plot[f1[x],{x,xmin1,xmax1}],Plot[f2[x],{x,xmin2,xmax2}]]`

Comment: @Subho95 Thank you, I was looking for a simple answer and it is one.

Comment: @StarBucK Happy to help!

Comment: being particular I think you mean simply different ranges on the same abscissa scale.

Comment: @george2079 this is indeed what i mean

Comment: @Subho95 actually your code doesn't work for me, i edit my message to show

Comment: @StarBucK I don't understand. What doesn't work?

Comment: @Subho95 I edited, see my message

Comment: @Subho95 ah it is just a matter of plotrange->All. Sorry i'm a beginner with mathematica

Comment: `Show[Plot[Sin[\[CapitalDelta]I], {\[CapitalDelta]I, -2, 0}], 
 Plot[Cos[\[CapitalDelta]I], {\[CapitalDelta]I, -1, 0}], 
 PlotRange -> All]`